# read() seeing null character instead of proper byte

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm reading in a binary file and adding the data to an RB-tree. In my file, the first four bytes are an ip address, the next four bytes are a number, and the next x bytes are a string terminated by a null character.

I realize I should be reading in a buffered amount of bytes, then processing that, but this is for an project which we're designing incrementally (so that step is next). So currently what I'm doing is reading one byte at a time and processing it, until I read a null character.

Here is what the relevant parts of my code look like:

```
int fd, i, check, numNames;
unsigned char fourBytes[4];
char curChar;
char buffer[255];

fd = open("converted", O_RDONLY);

check = read(fd, fourBytes, 4);
if(check < 4) break;
strcpy(m->ip, fourBytes);

check = read(fd, fourBytes, 4);
if(check < 4) break;
numNames = *(int *)fourBytes;

// I have a loop here but in the scheme of my current issue it doesn't matter
check = read(fd, curChar, 1);
```

This last line is where my issue is, curChar does not contain the next byte, it contains a null character (even though I know for a fact the next byte is not null). Why is this? I've tried messing with my data types, buffer sizes, using memset(), among other silly things. I'm not very familiar with system calls so I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You *cannot* cast pointers to `int *` like this, it is an aliasing error. You must use memcpy or an union.

Comment: Also `strcpy(m->ip, ...)` is wrong because `fourBytes` is certainly not a null-terminated stirng.

Comment: (Rather, you should be reading direnuctly into `m->ip`, `&numNames`...)

Comment: I'm unsure if that's related to my issue, because it does actually work. I'm just typecasting to an int array and then dereferencing. I'll try doing it differently but for all intents and purposes that part does work in my program.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Also I actually do add a null character to that array, I just didn't include that in my provided code. I'm almost 100% sure that the last line is where my real problem is.

Comment: It has **undefined** behaviour. One of the possible outcomes is that it works as expected... for now... unless it's the full moon...

Comment: "*I just didn't include that in my provided code*" - So how do you expect us to find the bugs in your program if what you're posting isn't even real code?

Comment: @melpomene Originally I was using fread() and fgetc() instead of read(), so I know which parts of the program work as far as dealing with the actual data-handling. When trying to use read(), the first eight bytes are read the exact same as with fread(), but when trying to use read() as fgetc() on the 9th byte, that's what doesn't work the same. So I'm really just trying to figure out what is wrong with that last line.

Comment: @Toy_Reid Your reasoning is faulty. You need to create a [mcve].

Comment: That needs to give a load of warnings, but none from the compiler output was provided. `curChar` is an integer converted to a pointer without a cast - that's a constraint error - surely you got at least **warning** for that.

Comment: `check = read(fd, curChar, 1)` will compile on gcc 7.1 with a warning `-wint-conversion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've given it here, `curChar` is a `char`, but you're passing it to `read(2)` as if it were a `char*`.  Since you don't mention getting a SIGSEGV, I'm sure this isn't your actual code...

Comment: And this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It does address the actual question: "curChar does not contain the next byte, it contains a null character (...). Why is this?".  I added the second sentence merely to explain that the explanation was wrong as well as the code.

Comment: In every example I've seen, if you're only reading one byte you do not have to read to a char*. Changing curChar to a char* and callocing one byte for it does not solve my problem.

Comment: You have misread your examples: they say something like `char c; read(fd,&c,1);` with an `&` that _makes_ a `char*`.

Comment: Well, it looks like you're absolutely correct and I'm embarrassed I didn't realize that. I'm very new to programming in C so thank you for not berating me haha.